# Otimizar código Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tenho um sistema para cadastrar negociação de débitos.
Suponhamos que cadastro uma negociação com 3 parcelas.
Sendo:

```
Parcela || Valor  || Vencimento || Situação
1       || 100,00 || 01/09/2017 || Pago
2       || 100,00 || 01/10/2017 || Pago
3       || 100,00 || 01/11/2017 || Aguardando Pagamento
```

Então, na listagem, eu quero exibir o status desta negociação em:

```
Acordo em dia
Acordo Quitado
Acordo Quebrado
```

Seguindo as seguintes regras, se todas as parcelas estiverem com situação `pago`, então a situação será `Acordo Quitado`, se houver ao menos uma parcela com situação `quebrado`, então a situação será `Acordo Quebrado` e se houver ao menos uma parcela com situação `Aguardando Pagamento` e nenhuma `Quebrado`, então a situação será `Acordo em dia`.

Eu fiz o seguinte teste com o código abaixo e funciona, mas acredito que isso seja gambiarra,
 portanto quero saber se existe outra forma de criar as informações que desejo,
 utilizando as regras acima.

```
        $this->db->select('situacao');
        $aguardando = $this->db->where('situacao', 0);
        $retorno_aguardando = $this->db->get('tbl_planilha_parcela')->num_rows();

        $quitado = $this->db->where('situacao', 1);
        $retorno_quitado = $this->db->get('tbl_planilha_parcela')->num_rows();

        $quebrado = $this->db->where('situacao', 2);
        $retorno_quebrado = $this->db->get('tbl_planilha_parcela')->num_rows();

        if($retorno_aguardando > 0 && $retorno_quebrado == 0)
        {               
            $situacao = 'Aguardando Pagamento';
        }
        else if($retorno_quebrado > 0)
        {               
            $situacao = 'Acordo Quebrado';
        }
        else if($retorno_aguardando == 0 && $retorno_quitado > 0 && $retorno_quebrado == 0)
        {               
            $situacao = 'Quitado';
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Se isto está dentro de um `controller` então não está muito bom.

O que eu faria:

1º - Criar um model para tratar com o banco (talvez já faça isso):

`application/models/Acordo_Model.php`

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Acordo_Model extends CI_Model
{
    public function recuperarSituacao($acordo_id) {
        $this->db->query("SELECT situacao, count(situacao) as qtd FROM tbl_planilha_parcela WHERE acordo_id = {$acordo_id} GROUP BY situacao");
        return $this->db->result_array();
    }
}
```

2º - Seu controller deve enviar o id do acordo e trabalhar os dados para saber em qual situação se encontra.

`application/controllers/situacao`:

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Situacao extends CI_Controller
{
    public function verificar()
    {
        $this->load->model('Acordo_Model', 'acordo');
        $acordo_id = $this->input->get('id');
        $situacoes = $this->acordo->recuperarSituaco($acordo_id);
        $situacao = $this->verificaSituacao($situacoes);

        echo $situacao;
    }

    private function verificaSituacao($items)
    {
        $situacao = array();

        foreach($items as $item) {
            $situacao[$item['situacao']] = $item['qtd'];
        }

        if($situacao[0] > 0 && $situacao[2] == 0) {
            return 'Acordo em dia';
        } else if($situacao[2] > 0) {               
            return  'Acordo Quebrado';
        } else if($situacao[0] == 0 && $situacao[1] > 0 && $situacao[2] == 0) {               
            return 'Acordo Quitado';
        }
    }
}
```

Por fim, acho que nem melhoramos muito, eu usei exatamente a sua lógica de "ifs" encadeados, apenas otimizei a consulta para uma única execução e passando o retorno para um array e criando um método para fazer a "checagem" evitamos ter que trabalhar com várias variáveis a mais, o índice do array são exatamente os status que utiliza no banco de dados.

Eu não acredito que sua abordagem seja uma "gambiarra" como disse, só mudei algumas coisas e introduzi o `acordo_id` para deixar as coisas mais legíveis.

Comment: Talvez o método `verificaSituacao` em enviaria para o `model` também, mas como não sou expert em arquitetura aguardemos os comentários dos `ninjas`

Comment: Revendo o meu código, pude perceber que não está correto, pois ele está pegando todas as negociações cadastradas e caso uma delas tenha alguma parcela que esteja dentro de alguma condição, então todas as negociações ficam com a mesma situação

Comment: Cada parcela deve ter um acordo_id e vc deve ter uma tabela de acordos com dados de quem é o cliente a data que o acordo foi fechado o valor total da dívida. E, caso tenha respondido sua pergunta, vote a favor e não deixe de indicar que ela respondeu sua pergunta :)

Comment: Estou testando o codigo e irei votar.